# How to know the count of lables or fiels in a screen using selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

Is there a way to find the count of fields or labels in a particular screen using Selenium IDE? If yes how can we record it?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0.1/reference.html#storeXpathCount), you can use

```
storeXpathCount(xpath, variableName)
```

to count the number of elements on the page, if you can find them via XPath.

Comment: For whole application we can find lables using only one "storeXpath" or for every lable we want to record 'xpath'

Comment: @user1488292 I'm sorry, what? Using `storeXpathCount | //label | someVariable`, you'll get the count of all `<label>` elements on the current page.

Comment: we want to use only one storexpathCount or for every label we want to storeXpathCount